# Cant zip application via gradle

Tags: gradle, zip

I am creating a deployment script in gradle. I need to zip up my application in order to upload it to s3 and deploy a revision via code deploy. I can manually run `zip -r Archive.zip *` to achieve this. However when I try to run the same command in gradle I get an error, please see debug log below.

Task:

```
task zip {
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir '.'
            commandLine 'zip', '-r', 'Archive.zip', '*'
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
13:01:24.961 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
13:01:24.961 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command 'zip'.
13:01:24.987 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
13:01:24.988 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
13:01:24.988 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command 'zip''
13:01:25.018 [QUIET] [system.out]
13:01:25.018 [QUIET] [system.out] zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r Archive.zip . -i *)
13:01:25.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
13:01:25.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'zip'' finished with exit value 12 (state: FAILED)
13:01:25.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute doLast {} action for :zip'
13:01:25.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
13:01:25.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':zip'
13:01:25.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :zip'
13:01:25.020 [null] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor]
13:01:25.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :zip' completed
13:01:25.020 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :zip (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.063 secs.
13:01:25.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.2 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
13:01:25.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Task worker for ':': released lock on root.1.2
13:01:25.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Task worker for ':': released lock on :
13:01:25.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]] finished, busy: 0.063 secs, idle: 0.002 secs
12:56:42.933 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run tasks'
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '/app/build.gradle' line: 50
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':zip'.
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'command 'zip'' finished with non-zero exit value 12
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
    12:56:42.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following task resolved my issue:

```
task zip {
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir '.'
            commandLine 'zip', '-r', 'Archive.zip', '.'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a clear message printed to stdout in your logs:

> 13:01:25.018 [QUIET] [system.out] zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip
>   -r Archive.zip . -i *)

Your command is invalid.

Also.. There's no need to run zip manually in gradle. There's a predefined [task](https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html) for that.

Comment: I tried the predefined task but it doesn't seem to zip anything and just hangs until I cancel it. Also when I run zip -r  Archive.zip * outside of gradle it is successful.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting?